# R get factor for legend

Tags: r, categorical-data

I‘m plotting data colored by category.

The category order is not alphabetically sorted, but meaningful

```
labels = c('V', 'A', 'UNKNOWN')

data = data.frame(
  x        = c(1,2,3),
  y        = c(4,5,6),
  category = factor(c('UNKNOWN', 'V', 'UNKNOWN'), labels))

plot(data$x, data$y, pch = 16, col = data$category)
legend('bottomright', labels, pch = 16, col = seq_along(labels))
```

now what if i actually want to exclude nonexisting levels from the legend?

I basically want an elegant way to get both the level names existing in `data$category` and their indices. But every way i can think of is very manual.

```
subset = which(labels %in% data$category)
label.subset = labels[subset]
```

PS: creating factor levels automatically is no option, as the colors should be stable across multiple plots with different subsets of those three categories.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the levels by factoring the subset again. I think you mean something like this for the legend.

```
legend('bottomright', levels(factor(data$category)), +
    pch = 16, col = seq_along(levels(factor(data$category))))
```

**Edit:** I missed the part about color preservation. This should work instead. As you've predefined levels, their order will stay intact.

```
legend('bottomright', levels(factor(data$category)), pch = 16, col = +
    which(levels(data$category) %in% levels(factor(data$category))))
```

Comment: your second solution is basically the same as mine, since integers behave the same as factors when used as `col` parameter: `subset = which(labels %in% data$category); legend('bottomright', labels[subset], col = subset)`

Comment: Well you do get to exclude the non-existant ones, but it is quite like yours. Sorry, I just know R well enough to "get things done". Perhaps someone might offer a more elegant solution if you're looking for one.

Comment: And maybe there is none. R is generally a more …practical… than elegant language